# How to visualize css coverage result from puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

I have simple html page:

```
<body>
  <h1>This is my sample page</h1>
  <div>This is my sample page content</div>
</body>
```

and simple css file for that:

```
div {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.aqua {
  color: aqua;
}

h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

I'm using puppeteer to get css coverage:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.coverage.startCSSCoverage()

  await page.goto('http://localhost:3000', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

  const cssCoverage = await page.coverage.stopCSSCoverage();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(cssCoverage, null, 2));
  await browser.close();
})();
```

From code above I've got output like:

```
[
  {
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/main.css",
    "ranges": [
      {
        "start": 4,
        "end": 58
      },
      {
        "start": 102,
        "end": 130
      }
    ],
    "text": "    div {\n      background: red;\n      color: white;\n    }\n\n    .aqua {\n      color: aqua;\n    }\n\n    h1 {\n      color: red;\n    }\n"
  }
]
```

Do you know any tool/library that may be used to nicely visualize coverage output I got ?

Answer (score 1):

@lusarz I'm not aware of any native reporter for puppeteer. However, there's a [puppeteer-to-istanbul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-to-istanbul) to generate istanbul reports.